# Como fazer input ser obrigatório via javascrip

Tags: php, html

me passem material de estudo,ouvi falar que tinha um pluguin via jquery.. me passem informacoes preciso colocar que um imput seja obrigatorio e aparesca um erro. tentei da maneira facil required porem n foi!

```
<input type="email" id="user_id" name="user_id" placeholder="" autocomplete="on" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" class="andes-form-control__field" maxlength="120" autofocus="">
```

Comment: required não funcionou... Coloca seu código, por favor.

Comment: pronto eu ja add

Comment: Fiz um teste com o required e funcionou, seu input está dentro de um formulário (form)?

Comment: me fala exatamente onde devo colocar o required entao , em algo estou errando ou edite pra mim por favor!

Answer (score 0):

O required fica dentro no input, porém seu input deve estar dentro de um formulário, abaixo um exemplo, se tiver dúvida, pegue esse trecho e faça um teste:

```html
<form>
  <input required type="email" id="user_id" name="user_id" placeholder="" autocomplete="on" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" class="andes-form-control__field" maxlength="120" autofocus="">
  <input type="submit">
<form>
```